# ModelMapper - How to use map(source, destination.class, typeMapName)?

Tags: java, deserialization

I am using a `ModelMapper` in my java application to transform a DTO into a POJO.

I have a class `MyObjectDto` that must be turned into `MyObject` to be used as an entity and sent to the database.

I have a use case where I receive `MyObjectDto` with an `id` property, which will tell my ORM that I must update the existing entity in database. This use case works fine.

Now I have another use case where I receive the same `MyObjectDto` except I want to create a new one in the database. One thing that could work, I thought, would be to use a specific mapping where I skip the `id` property to have my ORM understand this is a `create` operation and not an `update`.

I thought the method below would solve my problem:

```
public <D> D map(Object source,
                 Class<D> destinationType,
                 String typeMapName)
```

Except I don't know how to use it. So far I tried to do this:

```
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        TypeMap<MyObjectDto, MyObject> typeMapForNew = modelMapper.createTypeMap(MyObjectDto.class, MyObject.class)
                .addMappings(mapping -> mapping.skip(MyObject::setId));

        return modelMapper;
    }
```

This method is inside a configuration. Then I thought I'd call it like so but it gives a normal mapping:

```
    myObject = modelMapper.map(myObjectDto, MyObject.class, "typeMapForNew");
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: for this specific example, I did wrong in the configuration class. I should have done like this:

```
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(MyObjectDto.class, MyObject.class, "typeMapForNew")
                .addMappings(mapping -> mapping.skip(MyObject::setId));

        return modelMapper;
    }
```

Then I can use the named mapping and it works. I now need to understand how I can skip ID fields of my object sub entities. But the original question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Following REST guidelines, you should not send `id` in your DTO at all.

Create:

```
@POST
/rest/items
{ ...dto... } -> mapper -> Entity with null id -> save
```

Update:

```
@PUT
/rest/items/{id}
{ ...dto... } -> mapper -> Entity with null id -> set id from URL -> save
```

Comment: In my case I have lots of sub-entities and I need to know their ID in case of an update. I could try and make it so that I don't actually need these IDs and just create new sub-entities instead of updating them, that's something I need to think of.
Aside from this aspect, I would still try to understand if I can use different mappings for different situations and the same `(DTO, Entity)` couple with the `ModelMapper`.